# Mage.Cookies.clear() not working

Tags: javascript, magento-1, cookie

The JavaScript function `Mage.Cookies.clear` does not clear any cookie. It does not matter if the cookie was set with `Mage.Cookies.set` or from PHP.

Cookie configuration:

- Cookie Lifetime: 3600
- Cookie Path: /
- Cookie Domain: www.example.com
- Use HTTP Only: No
- Cookie Restriction Mode: No

I noticed it on Magento EE 1.14.2 but tagging the question as [magento-1](/questions/tagged/magento-1) since it seems to be a general problem in `cookies.js` which has not changed in ages.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having a look at the function:

```
Mage.Cookies.clear = function(name) {
  if(Mage.Cookies.get(name)){
    document.cookie = name + "=" +
    "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";
  }
};
```

it looks like path and domain are missing. Also the date string is not in the correct format (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136372/which-date-formats-can-i-use-when-specifying-the-expiry-date-when-setting-a-cook)

The function is not used anywhere in core Magento, probably that's why nobody noticed it was broken for 8 years.

I was able to fix this by redefining the function to use `Mage.Cookies.set` which takes care of all required parameters:

```
Mage.Cookies.clear = function(name) {
  if(Mage.Cookies.get(name)){
    Mage.Cookies.set(name, '', new Date(0));
  }
};
```

While we're at it, `Mage.Cookies.set` uses [`Date.toGMTString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString) which is **deprecated** and while it's still widely supported, it will not work in future browser versions. Changing it to `toUTCString` makes the cookie functions future proof.